# Installing Qt Creator on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, clang

I'm trying to install Qt on OS X v10.11. I'm using the installer `qt-unified-mac-x64-2.0.3-online`. It is now showing a sheet:

> You need to install Xcode version 5.0.0.
>   Download Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/xcode

Attempting to dismiss the sheet (pressing "OK") causes it to reappear.

The current version of Xcode is 7.3. As best I can tell, it is only available through the App Store, and thus only the latest version can be downloaded.

[This page](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/165647) from 6 months ago claims that Xcode 7 is not supported. However, that page cites [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html) as the source, and that source page says only that Clang is needed. "Xcode" does not appear on the page.

I have Clang:

```
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang

$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

…yet the Qt online installer will not allow me to continue.

What is the minimum software that I need to install on OS X to get Qt Creator installed and functional?

---

**Update**: I posted this question after pressing "OK" approximately 4 times. After posting the question I pressed "OK" in frustration approximately 5 more times. Eventually, it went away and allowed the installation to continue. (!)

However, when I try to build a project Qt Creator complains "Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`."

Running that command shows:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer
directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

So it looks like I do need Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. It seems I had the XCode command line tools installed as well and there is a way to select between them:

```
$ xcodebuild
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

$ xcode-select -p # Print currently selected xcode tools
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app # Select the XCode app.
```

After that it worked.